# all possible combinations from a configuration space model

Tags: python, combinations

I need to generate all possible combinations from a space which has options and each options has its own values.

As an example,

```
option 1: {1,2,3}
option 2: {4,5}
option 3: {2,3}
```

Combinations are going to be in the format, (v1, v2, v3) which is v1,v2 and v3 are coming from the option 1, option 2 and option 3 respectively. I will have output of 12 lists as below;

```
(1,4,2), (1,4,3), (1,5,2), (1,5,3), (2,4,2), (2,4,3), (2,5,2), (2,5,3), (3,4,2), (3,4,3), (3,5,2), (3,5,3)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This is called the cartesian product. Hence the name of itertools.product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all combinations:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> option1 = {1, 2, 3}
>>> option2 = {4, 5}
>>> option3 = {2, 3}
>>> for tup in product(option1, option2, option3):
...     print tup
... 
(1, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 3)
(1, 5, 2)
(1, 5, 3)
(2, 4, 2)
(2, 4, 3)
(2, 5, 2)
(2, 5, 3)
(3, 4, 2)
(3, 4, 3)
(3, 5, 2)
(3, 5, 3)
```

`itertools.product()` is a *generator*; it produces combinations on demand as the `for` loop loops over it, or you can ask it for a new combination each time with the `next()` function. This makes `itertools.product()` very memory efficient. Because it is implemented entirely in C, `itertools.product()` is also very *fast*, faster than a list comprehension would be.

To generate a list, call `list()` on it:

```
>>> list(product(option1, option2, option3))
[(1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (1, 5, 2), (1, 5, 3), (2, 4, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 2), (2, 5, 3), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 3), (3, 5, 2), (3, 5, 3)]
```

Time comparisons between `itertools.product` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("list(product(option1, option2, option3))", "from __main__ import option1, option2, option3, product")
1.6326439380645752
>>> timeit.timeit("[(x, y, z) for x in option1 for y in option2 for z in option3]", "from __main__ import option1, option2, option3, product")
2.2882919311523438
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in Python.

```
>>> op1 = {1,2,3}
>>> op2 = {4,5}
>>> op3={2,3}
>>> ans = [(x,y,z) for x in op1 for y in op2 for z in op3]
>>> ans
[(1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (1, 5, 2), (1, 5, 3), (2, 4, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 2), (2
, 5, 3), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 3), (3, 5, 2), (3, 5, 3)]
```

The one line answer would be

```
[(x,y,z) for x in {1,2,3} for y in {4,5} for z in {2,3}]
```

Comment: Number of options and values are not fixed. Actually I will use this for the large spaces. So I think using itertools.product() is better. Thanks anyway